# How can I select only one record per “person”, per date with an inner join in an MS Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, subquery, inner-join

I need to pull data from two tables: `Neptune_FN_Analysis` and `Neptune_prem`
There will be 3 fields called `readings_miu_id` (comparable to a persons name or item #), `ReadDate`, `ReadTime` (all of which are in `Neptune_FN_Analysis`). Some `readings_miu_id`s have multiple `ReadTime`s for multiple days but I only want to pull the "last time" entered per `readings_miu_id`, per day.
I need all `readings_miu_id`s that have an entry date for the selected range but only the last `ReadTime` entered for each record I am pulling.

My solution so far, based on one table is:

```
SELECT readings_miu_id, Reading, ReadDate, ReadTime, MIUwindow, SN, Noise, RSSI, OriginCol, ColID, Ownage
FROM analyzed AS A
WHERE ReadDate Between #4/21/2009# and #4/29/2009# 
AND ReadTime=
    (SELECT TOP 1 analyzed.ReadTime FROM analyzed 
    where analyzed.readings_miu_id = A.readings_miu_id 
    AND analyzed.ReadDate = A.ReadDate
    ORDER BY analyzed.ReadTime DESC);
```

When I try to adapt this solution, I can't do the `FROM [tableName] as A, INNER JOIN` because it gives me an error. The original code that my predecessor made (which is what I am trying to adapt/fix) is as follows:

```
SELECT readings_miu_id, Reading, ReadDate,Format([MIUtime],'hh:mm:ss') AS 
ReadTime, MIUwindow, SN, Noise, RSSI, ColRSSI, MIURSSI, Firmware, CFGDate, FreqCorr, 
Active, MeterType, OriginCol, ColID, Ownage, SiteID, PremID, Neptune_prem.prem_group1, 
Neptune_prem.prem_group2, ReadID 
INTO analyzed  
FROM Neptune_FN_Analysis INNER JOIN 
Neptune_prem ON Neptune_FN_Analysis.PremID = Neptune_prem.premice_id 
WHERE  SiteID = 36801 and ReadDate BETWEEN #04/21/09# AND #04/27/09#  
and OriginCol = 'US 29'    and ColID = 1 and ColID <> 0 and Active = 'Y'
```

Comment: Please reformat your question using the Code Sample button where appropriate. Or prefix ever line of code with 4 spaces for the same end result.

Comment: So does anyone know why I'm being down-voted here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite get all of what you're trying to do, but if you inner join on a subquery which gets the MAX of date, it could eliminate all the records where the date was not the max

```
SELECT readings_miu_id, Reading, ReadDate, ReadTime, MIUwindow, SN, 
Noise, RSSI, OriginCol, ColID, Ownage 
FROM analyzed 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT [whatever the id common to all like records is] as likeID, MAX(analyzed.ReadTime) as latestDate
 FROM analyzed 
 GROUP BY likeID) AS maxDate ON analyzed.likeID=maxDate.likeID AND analyzed.latestDate = maxDate.latestDate
WHERE ReadDate Between #4/21/2009# and #4/29/2009#
```

modify as needed

Comment: the table analyzed is the one i was using for testing. it is not being used used in the inner join statement. the inner Join statement is being used to create the "analyzed" table. Basically the second codeset in the question is the code im trying to use

Comment: its just an example, the table names could be "foo". the concept of using a subquery that gets MAX(date) grouped by the ID that is common to the records that have multiple entries is one possible solution to your problem. Apply your own table and field names to the example.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT a.readings_miu_id, a.Reading, a.ReadDate, a.ReadTime, a.MIUwindow, a.SN, a.Noise, a.RSSI, a.OriginCol, a.ColID, a.Ownage
FROM analyzed AS A INNER JOIN
          (SELECT max(ReadTime) as MaxReadTime,readings_miu_id FROM analyzed 
             WHERE ReadDate Between #4/21/2009# and #4/29/2009#
              GROUP BY readings_miu_id) as B 
             on a.readings_miu_id = b.readings_miu_id  and a.MaxReadTime = b.ReadTime
```

Comment: the table analyzed is the one i was using for testing. it is not being used used in the inner join statement. the inner Join statement is being used to create the "analyzed" table. Basically the second codeset in the question is the code im trying to use

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
     <your columns>
FROM
     Neptune_FN_Analysis A1
INNER JOIN Neptune_prem ON
     P.premice_id = A1.PremID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Neptune_FN_Analysis A2 ON
     A2.readings_miu_id = A1.readings_miu_id AND
     A2.ReadDate = A1.ReadDate AND
     A2.ReadTime > A1.ReadTime
WHERE
     A2.readings_miu_id IS NULL AND
     <add any additional criteria here>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you imply by specifying "`INNER JOIN`" this time around. Other answers use a subquery, so here's a an example using two `INNER JOIN`s and no subquery. Rather than getting my head around your schema :) I'm using Northwind to return customers and the date of their most recent order:

```
SELECT C1.CustomerID, C1.CompanyName, 
       O1.OrderID, O1.OrderDate
  FROM (Customers AS C1
       INNER JOIN Orders AS O1
          ON C1.CustomerID = O1.CustomerID)
       INNER JOIN Orders AS O2
          ON C1.CustomerID = O2.CustomerID
 GROUP 
    BY C1.CustomerID, C1.CompanyName, 
       O1.OrderID, O1.OrderDate
HAVING O1.OrderDate = MAX(O2.OrderDate);
```